# The socket.io is emitting to all rooms instead of the specified ones

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I'm new to node and socket io. I'm trying to implement a realtime notification system for couple of my own apps. So, using node, express and socket io, the code is given below:

Server Side Code:

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {

    socket.on('subscribe', function(room) {
        socket.join(room);
    });

    socket.on('unsubscribe', function(room) {
        socket.leave(room);
    });
});
```

Client Side Code:

```
var sio = io.connect('http://localhost:9000');

var ch1 = sio.emit('subscribe', 'channel1');

ch1.on('log', function (data) {
    console.log('channel1: ', data);
});

var ch2 = sio.emit('subscribe', 'channel2');

ch2.on('log', function (data) {
    console.log('channel2: ', data);
});
```

I'm firing/emitting the event from a route (express) for example:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {

    var data1 = {
        channel: 'channel1',
        evennt: 'log',
        message: 'Hello from channel1...'
    };

    io.to(data1.channel).emit(data1.event, data1);
});
```

When I'm hitting the route, the `io.to(data1.channel).emit(data1.event, data1);` is working but it sending the data to both rooms/channels but I was expecting to get the data only in `ch1` because `data1.channel` contains `channel1` so I was expecting the following handler will receive the data:

```
ch1.on('log', function (data) {
    console.log('channel1: ', data);
});
```

Notice that, both channels have same `log` event. Am I on the right track. Is it possible at all?

Comment: You mistyped `channel` in the declaration of `data1`.

Comment: It was a typo here but it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

```
var ch1 = sio.emit('subscribe', 'channel1');
var ch2 = sio.emit('subscribe', 'channel2');
```

You're subscribing the same socket (`sio`) to both rooms. Also, `ch1` and `ch2` are references to `sio`.

If you want to test it properly, you should create a second socket for the second channel:

```
var sio2 = io.connect('http://localhost:9000');
var ch2  = sio2.emit('subscribe', 'channel2');
```

Comment: You want to create multiple sockets, where each socket subscribes to a different room, but all sockets share the same connection? Is that correct?

Comment: By calling `sio2 = io.connect('http://localhost:9000')` works but those are two different connections.

Comment: I don't think that's possible. Connections are re-used if they connect to different _namespaces_, but not when multiple clients connect to the same namespace (which is what you want). More info here: https://socket.io/docs/client-api/#with-multiplexing